# MS access check box on a form

Tags: database, ms-access, ms-access-forms

I looked in the "similar questions" and could not locate one like I have. I'm using Access to print labels for an event and there are 200+ volunteers to whom we will mail out their event package. I'm looking for a way to show all their names (thinking on a form) AND have a check box for the "print label." Once everything I need is checked, I open a report via command button and the selected names are printed on labels. Also, is there a way to store the date / time printed, so I can use that as a "was this label printed? function. [image]I took a crack at what it would look like using Excel (see graphic),

Answer (score 2):

First, create and fill a *table* holding the name, perhaps some other fields, and a Yes/No field:

```
ID - FullName - (other fields) - PrintLabel
```

Then, create a *continuous form* using this table as source (there is a wizard for this).

Finally, modify your *report* to use this table as source and specify a filter:

```
PrintLabel = True
```